# AngularJS - Using JSON contents to determine name of string for replacement in HTML contents

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm creating a new Web application using AngularJS. it consists of a main page with a side menu, whose structure is pre-defined via a JSON file. The JSON would look something like the following (highly simplified!!):

```
G_Main_Menu = {
                "Management":
                           [{"Command":"DoThis","Label":"Label_DoThis"},
                            {"Command":"DoThat","Label":"Label_DoThat"}],
                "Others":
                           [{"Command":"DoOther","Label":"Label_DoOther"}]
              }
```

On the other hand, within the HTML page I would be deploying labels extracted from the database (it is a multi-lingual application and hence the contents of the labels would depend on the language selected by the user):

```
...{{ThisIstheLabelFor_DoThis}}...
...
...{{ThisIstheLabelFor_DoThat}}...
...
...{{ThisIstheLabelFor_DoOther}}...
```

The JSON as received from the database would look like:

```
{"Management":
   {"Label_DoThis":"This is the explicit contents of label DoThis",
    :
    "Label_DoThat":"This is the explicit contents of label DoThat",
    :
   },
 "Others":
   {"Label_DoOther":"This is the explicit contents of label DoOther"
   }
}
```

So, I have a JSON that contains a string specifying the **name** of the element contained in a second JSON.

How could I implement such indirect extraction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for the label in the translation JSON using a function

```
{{::translate(ThisIstheLabelFor_DoThis, category)}}
```

where category could be "Management" etc.

And the translate function could be implemented like this:

```
$scope.translate = function(label_name, category){
    return TranslateJson[category][label_name];
}
```

Comment: thank you @Robert. I was thinking that this had to be done via a function, but was not sire of that. Will give it a try and let you know. By the way, I was not aware of the syntax `::`. Is it AngularJS or Angular2?

Comment: Angular 1, it's one way binding, you can read more about this here https://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html

Comment: COOL!!!!!!!!!!!!! Just read the reference and it is EXACTLY my case (internationalized application). Than you very much for this!!!

Comment: One more question @Robert: In the function, I assume that `category` stands or `Management` or `Others` and `label_name` for `Label_DoThis`, `Label_DoThat`, etc., right? What I don't quite understand is where `TranslateJson` is coming from. I don't recall seeing this as an AngularJS method or anywhere else. Could you elaborate a little bit on this? Thanks again.

Comment: TranslateJson is the JSON returned by the server that contains the translated labels. {"Management":
   {"Label_DoThis":"This is the explicit contents of label DoThis",
    :
    "Label_DoThat":"This is the explicit contents of label DoThat",
    :
   },
 "Others":
   {"Label_DoOther":"This is the explicit contents of label DoOther"
   }
}

Comment: Accepting the answer: Just for you to know, I NEVER ignore the effort and time spent by people (like you in this case) trying to help others (like me). I quite hate when my answers (being THE ANSWER) are left with no approval, so I'm not going to do it here. Your answer is accepted of course. By the way, thanks for the clarification (about `TranslateJson`).

Comment: You're welcome. I did no mean to imply that you do not want to accept the answer but is easier for me to manage my answer if it is accepted.

Comment: Don't worry Robert, I took it the way you meant it, in a positive way. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let gMainMenu = {
  "Management": [{
      "Command": "DoThis",
      "Label": "Label_DoThis"
    },
    {
      "Command": "DoThat",
      "Label": "Label_DoThat"
    }
  ],
  "Others": [{
    "Command": "DoOther",
    "Label": "Label_DoOther"
  }]
};

let db = {
  "Management": {
    "Label_DoThis": "This is the explicit contents of label DoThis",
    "Label_DoThat": "This is the explicit contents of label DoThat",
  },
  "Others": {
    "Label_DoOther": "This is the explicit contents of label DoOther"
  }
};


Object.values(gMainMenu).forEach(menu => {
  menu.forEach(item => {
    let explicitContent = null;
    for (let d of Object.values(db)) {
      let key = Object.keys(d).find(k => k === item.Label);
      if(key){
        explicitContent = d[key];
      }
    }
    item.Label = explicitContent;
  });
});

console.log(gMainMenu);
```